# App Engine Google Oauth on dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

Goal:  To get actual user email on dev server when using OAuth 2.

Current Behavior:  User service always returns example@example.com.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?  This would be very helpful for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/#Java_OAuth_and_App_Engine)

On the local development server, oauth.getCurrentUser() always returns a User object with email set to "example@example.com" and user ID set to 0 regardless of whether or not a valid OAuth request was made.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case.  There is a work around that I may post here.  You can take the auth token passed in the request and hit the google token info api.  This will give you the email and google id.